# when I run springboot, The console show this error, what can I do to fix it?

Tags: java

2021-05-15 17:23:06.994 [main] ERROR o.s.b.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter:40 -

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
javax.el.ELManager.getExpressionFactory(ELManager.java:38)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
javax.el.ELUtil.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
```

The method's class, javax.el.ELUtil, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/tan/Desktop/jeecg-boot/jeecg-boot/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jar!/javax/el/ELUtil.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/tan/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.el/3.0.3/jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar!/javax/el/ELUtil.class
```

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
javax.el.ELUtil: file:/C:/Users/tan/Desktop/jeecg-boot/jeecg-boot/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.el.ELUtil

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace and the error message?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I added details about the error

Comment: sharing complete stacktrace would help

Comment: This looks like you have a version problem. Can you please share your pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for you guys attention, I have fix the bug by delete "jar:file:/C:/Users/tan/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.el/3.0.3/jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar!/javax/el/ELUtil.class"